# undefined is not a constructor AngularJS Jasmin/Karma Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I'm trying to run unit test cases for my AngularJS code. But, when I use the app name from my app.js it's throwing an error. It's working fine when initializing the module in the particular controller.

For this example, I have my test and src file in the same folder.

Karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    basePath: '../',    
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
        'assets/libs/angular/angular.min.js',
        'assets/libs/angular/angular-mocks.js',

        'app/**/*.js',
        'app/**/*.html',
        'tests/sum.js',
        'tests/sum.spec.js'
    ],
    exclude: [
    ],
    preprocessors: {
    },
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    singleRun: false,
    plugins: [
      'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
      'karma-jasmine',
      'karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor',
      'karma-coverage',
      'karma-junit-reporter',
      'karma-threshold-reporter',
      'karma-htmlfile-reporter'
    ],
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({

          karma: {
            unit: {
              configFile: 'config/karma.conf.js',
              autoWatch: true
            }
          }


        });

      grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-karma');

  };
```

sum.spec.js

```
describe('trinetApp level 1', function () {

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('cookbook'));
  var $controller;

  beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function(_$controller_){
    $controller = _$controller_;
  }));

  describe('trinetApp level 2', function () {
      it('should assign the correct rapper to scope', function () {
          var $scope = {};
          var controller = $controller('MainCtrl', { 
              $scope: $scope
          });
          $scope.x = 1;
          $scope.y = 2;
          $scope.sum();
          expect($scope.result).toBe(1+2);
      }); 
  });
});
```

sum.js

```
angular.module('cookbook', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.sum = function () {
        $scope.result = $scope.x + $scope.y;
    }
});
```

But the unit test is not successful when I have my controller attached to the app name like below.

app.js

```
var appName = angular.module('myApp', 
   ['ui.bootstrap','ui.bootstrap4','TrinetPassport.templates','ngRoute',
    'ngResource', 'ngSanitize', 'ngDialog', 'tc.chartjs', 'ngDraggable',
    'ngMask',
    'ngStorage', 'ui.sortable', 'ui.select', 'ngCookies', 'angular.filter',
    'ngTagsInput', 'vAccordion', 'ngMaterial', 'angulartics',
    'angulartics.google.analytics','d3','infinite-scroll',
    'ui.router','ngMap','ngIdle']);
```

sum.js (not working)

```
appName.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.sum = function () {
        $scope.result = $scope.x + $scope.y;
    }
});
```

Is there any way to initialize the controller with app name rather than using angular.module in each of my controller??